# Spark installed but no command 'hdfs' or 'hadoop' found

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am a new pyspark user.
I just downloaded and installed a spark cluster ("spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz")
after installation I wanted to access the file system (upload local files to cluster). But when I tried to type hadoop or hdfs in command it will say "no command found".

Am I gonna install hadoop/HDFS (I thought it's built in the spark, I don't get)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you installed Hadoop prior installing Spark? you installed Spark supporting hadoop version if hadoop is not installed..Hadoop commands will not work..

Comment: You can install Apache Spark in Standalone mode and as  well as on top of Apache hadoop. I think you installed in standalone mode thats the reason you are not able to access hdfs file system.

Comment: @Bhavesh Legit! I was stupid. Thank you. I thought the one I downloaded comes with HDFS

Comment: @css2607 yes you are right. thank you. Am I gonna install Apache hadoop first and then use the one I downloaded to setup spark cluster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to install hadoop first to access HDFS. 
Follow this http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

Choose the latest version of hadoop from the apache site.
Once you done with hadoop setup go to spark http://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz download this, Extract files. Setup java_home and hadoop_home in spark-env.sh.

Comment: Thank you. ok then I will install hadoop then. Do I need to delete my current spark? And another question is if I want to use the HDFS for my spark cluster, do I need to install hadoop for all of my nodes?

Comment: Yes you can remove old spark, I gave you the answer about single node spark/hadoop, you need to configure multiNode hadoop and then configure spark.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try it out and see how it goes!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `hdfs` or `hadoop` on **classpath** so this is the reason why you are getting message: *"no command found"*.

If you run `\yourparh\hadoop-2.7.1\bin\hdfs dfs -ls /` it should works and show root content.

But, You can add your `hadoop/bin` (`hdfs`, `hadoop` ...) commands to classpath with something like this:

```
export PATH $PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

where `HADOOP_HOME` is your env. variable with path to `hadoop` [installation folder (download and install **is required**)](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GettingStartedWithHadoop)

Comment: thank you, I think spark installation doesn't come with HDFS. I will try to download and install hadoop and see how it goes.